# How to load dynamic website (java,spring) as webpage in another website (java)

Tags: java, html, spring, routes

We are planning to integrate one of our dynamic website developed using java,spring into another website page developed using java. For example: We have main website called http://www.mainsite.com. If I give an url like http://www.mainsite.com/dynamic then I need to load dynamic website and it should work as usual. Please share your thoughts to achieve this. If this is not the right way, pros and cons are welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you need to display one website inside another website ? or do you want to have both website up and running at the same time but with different urls (which you specified above) ?

Answer (score 0):

An iframe should work, it should be something like this:

like

```
<iframe src="http://www.mainsite.com/dynamic">Test</iframe>
```